# Decimal Separators

Tags: microsoft-excel

Can I have individual excel files using commas on some and periods on others as decimal separators? Some of my files are only used on European documents. Whilst others are strictly USA.

Thank you
PRDIGM

Answer (score 2):

The use of decimal point versus decimal comma is set with the computer's regional settings. You normally don't need to change that, because Excel will do that job for you. More than that, Excel also changes the language used for formulas to reflect the language set that is installed with Office.

If someone in a European country, say Germany, writes a Vlookup function, it will look like

```
=SVerweis(foo;bar;baz;false)
```

The function name is not VLookup and the parameters are separated by semicolons, not commas. A decimal number with thousand separator will look like `12.345,66`

When that very same Excel file is opened on a computer with US settings (using decimal point), the formula will look like this:

```
=VLookup(foo,bar,baz,false)
```

The formula will be shown in the language of the Office installation on the current computer. The number will look like this `12,345.66', again using the regional settings of the current computer.

You can override the regional settings of the computer in Excel and set the decimal, thousand and list separator manually (or using a VBA macro), but why would you want to? It will only add confusion and invite problems.

With Excel using consistent symbols on one machine and translating symbols automatically, there should never by a need to manually change the settings for Excel to work correctly.

The only reason I can think of is when you want to copy/paste a formula into a user guide or take a screenshot. If your computer uses US settings and you are writing documentation for people who are using European settings, then you may want to change the settings before taking the screenshots, and you may want to install language packs that enable switching between languages used for Excel functions.

Comment: This reply has cleared up more than just my original question. Thank you.

Comment: if this solved your issue, please mark it as the answer as explained in the [tour]. That is how you can say "thank you" on this site.

Answer (score 1):

You can if you use the following Macro in the sheet:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Activate()
    Application.DecimalSeparator = ","
    Application.ThousandsSeparator = "."
    Application.UseSystemSeparators = False
End Sub

Private Sub Workbook_Deactivate()
    Application.UseSystemSeparators = True
End Sub
```

There is no other way, but depending on Windows policies in your or the receiving company, this may ring all sorts of alarm bells. You also need to close the workbook to revert the change to EU or US, however you configure it.